# How to detect method calling with block using RSpec

Tags: ruby

I want to detect method calling with block using RSpec.

`Deck#split_even_number` is split numbers into even or odd. I want to detect `Enumerable#partition` is called with block.

I try using `Proc.new { ... }`, but this expectation is always failed.
I thins each `Proc` instance have different object id.

How to solve this..?

```
class Deck
  def split_even_numbers
    @cards.partition { |card| card.even? }
  end
end

describe Deck do
  describe '#split_even_numbers' do
    let(:deck) { Deck.new(cards) }
    let(:cards) { [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] }


    # this test is more desirable than to detect method calling
    it do
      even, odd = deck.split_even_numbers

      aggregate_failures do
        expect(even).to match_array([2, 4])
        expect(odd).to match_array([1, 3, 5])
      end
    end

    it do
      expect(cards).to receive(:partition).with(no_args) do |&block|
        expect(block).to eq(Proc.new{ |card| card.even? })
      end
      deck.split_even_numbers
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would argue that you should not test how a method is working (using `partition` and `even?`) but that it returns the expected result (`[[2,4], [1,3,5]]` in this example). Because the way to solve a problem might be refactored and change over time, but the method should even after a refactoring return the correct result. Furthermore, in your example, you never test that it actually returns the correct result. Just calling methods in the order that developer thought would return a correct result, doesn't guarantee that the result is actually correct.

Comment: @spickermann your opinion is correct. I have added test in my question, but  main purpose is to detect method calling with block. This is just my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the block form of `receive` you can get a handle on the proc that is passed. However, there is no way to really dig into the contents of the block. The only option is to make the proc publically accessible (a form of dependency injection):

```
class Deck
  ProcCallingEven = Proc.new(&:even?)
  def initialize(cards)
    @cards = cards
  end
  def split_even_numbers
    @cards.partition(&ProcCallingEven)
  end
end

describe Deck do
  describe '#split_even_numbers' do
    let(:cards) { [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] }
    let(:deck) { Deck.new(cards) }
    it do
      expect(cards).to receive(:partition) do |&block|
        expect(block).to be Deck::ProcCallingEven
      end
      deck.split_even_numbers
    end
  end
end
```

Although as already mentioned in comments To test something like this just makes sure that the code never changes. But code always changes just the result is supposed to be the same.

Comment: This doesn't work, procs aren't equal even if they do the same thing

Comment: i'm going to edit this to show how it would be feasible.